# URL limit for GET requests in IE7 seems to be surpassed

Tags: internet-explorer, url, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, get

There have been many questions here about URL length limits in various browsers, but I'm finding a strange situation and I'm curious if others have run into this.

The url character limit on Interent Explorer is well documented: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427
From my research, this article is not completely correct, however, as the IE8 limit I found to be exactly 4096 characters. Urls longer than this are obviously truncated.

In this application there is some Javascript executing a basic GET request, and because of a variety of factors the request length is usually around 1000 chars. However, there's a long tail distribution of character lengths and about 1% of requests currently fall above 3000 chars. My server is logging these requests and the browser identification info in a database. In my test environment (virtual machine running XP with IE7) the limit of 2083 chars seems to hold and the requests appear to fail.

Strangely, my production database has more than a few entries for IE7 far above the 2083 character limit, one even as long as 3043 characters.

My question relates to what might be the answer to this conflict of information. Is browser-spoofing prevalent enough to be the solution? (as in, is a Firefox user pretending to be IE7) Are there exceptions or a Microsoft patch that allow long urls to get through? Ideas are much appreciated.

(As a side note, I'm aware of practical fixes--shortening my url is a viable option and I'm looking into ways to keep lengths under 2000 such as POST or dropping parameters).

Comment: I would just use POST, as you say. That IE seems to allow more than 2083 characters in some cases is interesting, but really only in an academic sense.

Comment: IE uses `INTERNET_MAX_URL_LENGTH` declared in wininet.h.  I don't think it's changed.  But I haven't checked recently.